# VBA Crashing when pasting into Powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have made a macro which creates some graphs in excel and then opens powerpoint and pastes them into a template. Over the past couple of weeks and it has been working completely fine but after adding some things into the macro (which are completely separate things like refreshing data and setting filters) it seems to be crashing when pasting the graphs into powerpoint. Anyone else had similar issues in the past? There doesn't seem to be any reason why it should be doing it at all...

```
Sub PowerpointPres(r)
Dim PPT As Object
Dim PPApp As Object
Dim PPPres As Object
Dim PPSlide As Object
Dim PPShape As Shape

Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True

PPT.Presentations.Open filename:="S:\Commercial Finance\Macros for Standard Reporting\Country Manager Presentation Macro\CM Presentation Template.pptm"

Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation

'Slide 1
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(1)
PPSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Country Review YTD " & Year(Now())

'Slide 2
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(2)
PPSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Country Review YTD " & Year(Now())

'Slide 3
Pivots.ChartObjects(1).Copy

i = Pivots.Range("G14").Text
j = Pivots.Range("H14").Text

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(3)

With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " TCV YTD " & Year(Now()) - 1 & " and " & Year(Now()) & " - by Sector"
.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Totals:" & Year(Now()) - 1 & ":" & i & "" & Year(Now()) & ":" & j
End With
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (3)
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault).Select
'PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(3)
    .Top = 55
    .Left = 85
    .Height = 350
    .Width = 550
    With .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill
        .TwoColorGradient 2, 1
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 94, 140)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 165, 241)
        .GradientStops.Insert RGB(0, 138, 202), 0.5
    End With
    With .Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill
        .TwoColorGradient 2, 1
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(85, 85, 85)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(125, 125, 125)
        .GradientStops.Insert RGB(150, 150, 150), 0.5
    End With
End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'Slide 4
Pivots.ChartObjects(2).Copy

i = Pivots.Range("V14").Text
j = Pivots.Range("W14").Text

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(4)

With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " TCV YTD " & Year(Now()) - 1 & " and " & Year(Now()) & " - by Type"
.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Totals:" & Year(Now()) - 1 & ":" & i & "" & Year(Now()) & ":" & j
End With
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (4)
'PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault).Select
With PPSlide.Shapes(3)
    .Top = 55
    .Left = 85
    .Height = 350
    .Width = 550
    With .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill
        .TwoColorGradient 2, 1
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 94, 140)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 165, 241)
        .GradientStops.Insert RGB(0, 138, 202), 0.5
    End With
    With .Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill
        .TwoColorGradient 2, 1
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(85, 85, 85)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(125, 125, 125)
        .GradientStops.Insert RGB(150, 150, 150), 0.5
    End With
End With

'Slide 5
LRow = Pivots.Range("AH8").End(xlDown).Row
Pivots.Range("AH8:AI" & LRow).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(5)

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (5)
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 50
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 200
End With

Pivots.ChartObjects(3).Copy

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (5)
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " New TCV by AM YTD " & Year(Now())
End With
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(3)
    .Top = 80
    .Left = 300
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 350
End With

'Slide 6
LRow = Pivots.Range("AN8").End(xlDown).Row
Pivots.Rows("8:" & LRow).RowHeight = 20
Pivots.Range("AN8:AO" & LRow).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(6)

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (6)
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 50
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 200
End With

Pivots.ChartObjects(4).Copy

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (6)
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " New TCV by Product YTD " & Year(Now())
End With
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(3)
    .Top = 80
    .Left = 300
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 350
End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'Slide 7
LRow = Pivots.Range("AY8").End(xlDown).Row
Pivots.Range("AT1:AZ" & LRow).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(7)

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (7)
'PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2).Select
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Top 10 TCV New Deals Signed YTD " & Year(Now())
End With

With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 660
End With

'Slide 9
LRow = Pivots.Range("BG1").End(xlDown).Row
Pivots.Range("BD1:BG" & LRow).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(9)

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (9)
'PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2).Select
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " IR – Top 10 Customers YTD " & Year(Now())
End With

With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 660
End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'Slide 10
Pivots.ChartObjects(11).Copy

i = Pivots.Range("CZ19").Text
j = Pivots.Range("DA19").Text

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(10)

With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " New IIR YTD " & Year(Now()) - 1 & " and " & Year(Now()) & " - by Sales Sector"
.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Totals:" & Year(Now()) - 1 & ":" & i & "" & Year(Now()) & ":" & j
End With
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (10)
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault).Select
'PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(3)
    .Top = 55
    .Left = 85
    .Height = 350
    .Width = 550
    With .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill
        .TwoColorGradient 2, 1
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 94, 140)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 165, 241)
        .GradientStops.Insert RGB(0, 138, 202), 0.5
    End With
    With .Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill
        .TwoColorGradient 2, 1
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(85, 85, 85)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(125, 125, 125)
        .GradientStops.Insert RGB(150, 150, 150), 0.5
    End With
End With

'Slide 11

Pivots.ChartObjects(5).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(11)

LRow = Pivots.Range("BK:BO").Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

i = Pivots.Range("BL" & LRow).Text
j = Pivots.Range("BM" & LRow).Text
k = Pivots.Range("BN" & LRow).Text
l = Pivots.Range("BO" & LRow).Text

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (11)
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Monthly Net MRC YTD " & Year(Now())
With .Shapes(2)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "MRC Won " & Year(Now()) & " YTD:         € " & i
    .Top = 5
    .Left = 475
    .Height = 30
    .Width = 250
End With

With .Shapes(3)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "MRC Ceased " & Year(Now()) & " YTD:    € " & j
    .Top = 20
    .Left = 475
    .Height = 30
    .Width = 250
End With

With .Shapes(4)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "MRC Erosion " & Year(Now()) & " YTD:    € " & k
    .Top = 35
    .Left = 475
    .Height = 30
    .Width = 250
End With

With .Shapes(5)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Net MRC " & Year(Now()) & " YTD:           € " & l
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 475
    .Height = 30
    .Width = 250
End With

End With
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(6)
    .Top = 80
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 650
    With .Chart
        .ChartStyle = 2
        .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(246, 139, 31)
        .SeriesCollection(4).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(51, 51, 255)
    End With
End With

'Slide 12
LRow = Pivots.Range("BR1").End(xlDown).Row
Pivots.Range("BR1:BW" & LRow).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(12)

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (12)
'PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2).Select
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Net MRC - Top 10 Customer YTD " & Year(Now())
End With

With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 660
End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'Slide 13
Pivots.ChartObjects(6).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(13)

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (13)
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Revenue at Risk – MRC up for renewal"
End With
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 420
    .Width = 650
    .Chart.ChartStyle = 8
End With

'Slide 14
Pivots.ChartObjects(7).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(14)

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (14)
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Revenue at Risk – Top 10 MRC up for renewal " & Year(Now())
End With
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 420
    .Width = 650
    .Chart.ChartStyle = 8
End With

'Slide 15
Pivots.ChartObjects(8).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(15)
i = Year(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), Day(Now())))
j = Month(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), Day(Now())))
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (15)
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " – Top 5 MRC expiring " & Left(MonthName(j), 3) & "-" & i
End With
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 370
    .Width = 650
    .Chart.ChartStyle = 8
End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'Slide 16
Pivots.ChartObjects(9).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(16)
i = Year(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()) + 1, Day(Now())))
j = Month(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()) + 1, Day(Now())))
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (16)
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " – Top 5 MRC expiring " & Left(MonthName(j), 3) & "-" & i
End With
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 370
    .Width = 650
    .Chart.ChartStyle = 8
End With

'Slide 17
Pivots.ChartObjects(10).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(17)
i = Year(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()) + 2, Day(Now())))
j = Month(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()) + 2, Day(Now())))
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (17)
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " – Top 5 MRC expiring " & Left(MonthName(j), 3) & "-" & i
End With
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 370
    .Width = 650
    .Chart.ChartStyle = 8
End With

'Slide 18
Pivots.Range("FJ1:FO11").Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(18)

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (18)
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(1)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & ": SalesForce Pipeline & Top Deals"
    .Left = 100
    .Top = 10
    .Height = 50
    .Width = 650
End With

Pivots.Range("SalesForceTable2").Copy
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste

With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 130
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 320
    .Width = 660
End With

With PPSlide.Shapes(3)
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 50
    .Width = 660
End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'Slide 19
LRow = Pivots.Range("EC1").End(xlDown).Row

If LRow < 19 Then
Pivots.Range("EC1:EL" & LRow).Copy
Else
Pivots.Range("EC1:EL19").Copy
End If

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(19)

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (19)
'PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2).Select
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(1)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Individual Performance YTD " & Year(Now()) & " (pg1)"
    .Left = 20
    .Top = 20
    .Height = 50
    .Width = 650
End With

With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 660
End With

'Slide 20
If LRow > 19 Then

Pivots.Range("EM2:EV20").ClearContents

If LRow > 19 And LRow <= 37 Then
Pivots.Range("EC20:EL" & LRow).Copy
Else
Pivots.Range("EC20:EL37").Copy
End If

Pivots.Range("EM2").PasteSpecial xlValues

LRow2 = Pivots.Range("EM1").End(xlDown).Row

Columns("EM:EV").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Pivots.Range("EM1:EV" & LRow2).Copy

Set PPLayout = PPPres.Slides(19).CustomLayout
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.AddSlide(20, PPLayout)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(20)

With PPSlide
.Shapes(2).Delete
End With

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (20)
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(1)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 28
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Individual Performance YTD " & Year(Now()) & " (pg2)"
    .Left = 20
    .Top = 20
    .Height = 50
    .Width = 650
End With

With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 660
End With

Else

On Error GoTo ContinueHere

For i = PPApp.Slides.Count To 20 Step -1

PPPres.Slides(i).Delete

Next

On Error GoTo 0

End If

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'slide 21
If LRow > 37 Then

Pivots.Range("EM2:EV20").ClearContents

If LRow > 37 And LRow <= 55 Then
Pivots.Range("EC38:EL" & LRow).Copy
Else
Pivots.Range("EC38:EL55").Copy
End If

Pivots.Range("EM2").PasteSpecial xlValues

LRow2 = Pivots.Range("EM1").End(xlDown).Row

Columns("EM:EV").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Pivots.Range("EM1:EV" & LRow2).Copy

Set PPLayout = PPPres.Slides(19).CustomLayout
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.AddSlide(21, PPLayout)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(21)

With PPSlide
.Shapes(2).Delete
End With

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (21)
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(1)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 28
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Individual Performance YTD " & Year(Now()) & " (pg3)"
    .Left = 20
    .Top = 20
    .Height = 50
    .Width = 650
End With

With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 660
End With

Else

On Error GoTo ContinueHere

For i = PPApp.Slides.Count To 20 Step -1

PPPres.Slides(i).Delete

Next

On Error GoTo 0

End If

'Slide 22
If LRow > 55 Then

Pivots.Range("EM2:EV20").ClearContents

If LRow > 55 And LRow <= 73 Then
Pivots.Range("EC56:EL" & LRow).Copy
Else
Pivots.Range("EC56:EL73").Copy
End If

Pivots.Range("EM2").PasteSpecial xlValues

LRow2 = Pivots.Range("EM1").End(xlDown).Row

Columns("EM:EV").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Pivots.Range("EM1:EV" & LRow2).Copy

Set PPLayout = PPPres.Slides(19).CustomLayout
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.AddSlide(22, PPLayout)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(22)

With PPSlide
.Shapes(2).Delete
End With

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (22)
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(1)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 28
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Individual Performance YTD " & Year(Now()) & " (pg4)"
    .Left = 20
    .Top = 20
    .Height = 50
    .Width = 650
End With

With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 660
End With

Else

On Error GoTo ContinueHere

For i = PPApp.Slides.Count To 20 Step -1

PPPres.Slides(i).Delete

Next

On Error GoTo 0

End If

'slide 23
If LRow > 73 Then

Pivots.Range("EM2:EV20").ClearContents

If LRow > 73 And LRow <= 91 Then
Pivots.Range("EC74:EL" & LRow).Copy
Else
Pivots.Range("EC74:EL91").Copy
End If

Pivots.Range("EM2").PasteSpecial xlValues

LRow2 = Pivots.Range("EM1").End(xlDown).Row

Columns("EM:EV").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Pivots.Range("EM1:EV" & LRow2).Copy

Set PPLayout = PPPres.Slides(19).CustomLayout
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.AddSlide(23, PPLayout)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(23)

With PPSlide
.Shapes(2).Delete
End With

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (23)
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
With PPSlide.Shapes(1)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 28
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Individual Performance YTD " & Year(Now()) & " (pg5)"
    .Left = 20
    .Top = 20
    .Height = 50
    .Width = 650
End With

With PPSlide.Shapes(2)
    .Top = 70
    .Left = 30
    .Height = 380
    .Width = 660
End With

Else

On Error GoTo ContinueHere

For i = PPApp.Slides.Count To 20 Step -1

PPPres.Slides(i).Delete

Next

On Error GoTo 0

End If

ContinueHere:

PPApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs "S:\Commercial Finance\Macros for Standard Reporting\Country Manager Presentation Macro\Outputs\" & r & "\" & Format(Now(), "dd-MM-yyyy") & ".pptm"
PPApp.ActivePresentation.Close
PPApp.Quit

' Clean up
Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PPApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the relevant code.

Comment: The issue isn't about the code though. It crashes randomly wherever in the code. Not at exact points. Ill edit my original post anyway

Comment: That would be helpful as you cannot expect help on SO without some code for users to look over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned from you that the error it gives is `Shapes.PasteSpecial : Invalid request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here.`

The problem is that clipboard is not ready for pasting immediately after calling copy operation, but it needs some time to load the data. Let's give it the time:

1. Add small module containing this code:

   ```
   Option Explicit 

   #If VBA7 Then 
   Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems 
   #Else 
   Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems 
   #End If
   ```
2. Now insert the following delay between your copy and paste statements:

   ```
   Dim i as Integer
   For i = 1 To 6 
     DoEvents() 
     Sleep 500 'milliseconds
   Next i
   ```

This should give copy operation enough time to populate the clipboard.

You can adjust constant `"6"` in the above loop if it is too high or too low.