# Excel VBA PowerPoint chart copy closing mid formatting procedure

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I have a procedure which opens a .ppt template and copies in charts and tables from Excel for multi-generation of presentations (a Do Loop).  What appears to be an every-other-time event, the pasting of an Excel chart is interrupted mid-process, after entering a WITH statement, by closing the .ppt before completing the WITH and before the procedure performs PPT.Quit.  Therefore the program cannot find the presentation to format the shape on the slide.

My search has found no answers on how to remedy this or what would cause it to work only 1/2 of the time?  Here is the Code:

```
    'Slide 8 = Contour Overlay Chart
    Sheets("Contour Plot").Select
    'Copy Chart into PowerPoint
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ContourPlot").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ContourPlot").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ContourPlot").Chart.CopyPicture _
        appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes.PasteSpecial Link:=0
NumShape = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes.Count
With PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes(NumShape) 'Here is where it closes .ppt every OTHER instance from a loop before it gets to the next line
    .Height = 390
    .Left = 160
    .Top = 110
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Save and Close the PowerPoint presentation
PPT.ActivePresentation.Save
PPT.ActivePresentation.Close
'Stop the PowerPoint connection
PPT.Quit

'Clear the memory
Set PPT = Nothing
```

Comment: 1. Why do you activate the chart object twice? 2. It seems like the NumShape counted doesn't exist in PPT Slide, it could be that the starting object is 0 -_COULD BE_- try to "-1" to NumShape

Comment: Thanks @Sgdva, 1) The activation twice was my sad attempt to make sure the chart being selected wasn't an issue.  Which would not shut down .ppt prematurely, but it was worth a shot. 2) When I watch NumShape it is 2 upon selecting the slide. I will try what you suggest but do you have any idea why it is closing the PowerPoint at this line?

Comment: Did you try to catch if the numshape being counted is in the sheet?

Comment: Yep!  Just did that and it clearly is 2 but when it gets to the next line, shuts down PPT every OTHER time.  That's what I cannot grasp why it would be so specific.  I've even used a different data set to populate the chart and tables before copy and it makes no difference.  I should be clear that all PowerPoints being generated open the same skeleton template then save in a separate folder specific to the source data.  I'm baffled.

Comment: I've found that it's almost always more reliable to resize the chart object in Excel, in fact, do any and all formatting in Excel, then copy it, paste it into PowerPoint, position it if necessary, and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

This was a puzzle and I also encountered PowerPoint shutting down EVERY time I tried to paste the chart picture. So to solve this, I used a few things:

1. Create separate objects for the PowerPoint items (Application, Presentation, Slide). This gives you better control over how each object is acting on the data/object in process. It also is much clearer in debugging. Sure, you're creating more variables but it also produces clearer code.
2. My example uses early binding of the PowerPoint object library, but it can work just as well with late binding. I find it easier to work out the problems with early binding, just to get the code operational, then back it out to late binding if needed.
3. You don't need to `Select` and `Activate` in your code. It's almost never necessary because the objects themselves can take the appropriate action.
4. I ran across an interesting post [VBA Crashing When Pasting into PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28504964/4717755), that caused me to insert the delay timer shown below. Turns out the code runs fine without it, once I made sure all the PPT objects were correct.
5. My example code was forced to `SaveAs` due to how the original `Presentation` was opened.

The code below runs for me every time without error.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Sub CopyChartToPPT()
    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPR As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptSL As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim cplotSH As Worksheet
    Dim cplotChart As ChartObject
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim newestShape As Integer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set cplotSH = wb.Sheets("Contour Plot")
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pptPR = pptApp.Presentations.Open("junkppt1.pptx", ReadOnly:=msoTrue)
    Set pptSL = pptPR.Slides(8)

    Set cplotChart = cplotSH.ChartObjects("ContourPlot")
    cplotChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    'Dim i As Integer
    'For i = 1 To 6
    '  DoEvents
    '  Sleep 500 'milliseconds
    'Next i

    pptSL.Shapes.PasteSpecial
    newestShape = pptSL.Shapes.Count
    With pptSL.Shapes(newestShape)
        .Height = 390
        .Left = 160
        .Top = 110
    End With

    pptPR.SaveAs Filename:="differentname.pptx"
    pptPR.Close
    Set pptPR = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, @PeterT! Unfortunately, I get almost the same result.  The second "go 'round" it throws an error: "Slide (unknown member) : Object does not exist" - The PowerPoint is still open but still stops. So how does it lose the slide? I even added the timer and it still errors.  I am not an expert by any stretch of the imagination, but I have other macros that I've written opening, saving and closing this PowerPoint file with no issues. This really has me stumped.